# Looping over the parameters of a defined function in C++

Tags: c++, c, function, loops

I am rather a beginner in C++ and I don't know how to solve the following issue.
I have a working code which find the root of a function using the Brent method. The issue I am interested in is how to loop over different values of the parameters of the function, assuming the same specification.

Here is a simpler example. I call a function which call another defined function AFunction.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
double   x1,x2,res,r;


// Simple Function
double AFunction(double x) {
  return ((x)+2);
}


// A second function that call the first one


double AddF( double x1, double x2, double *res )  
{
 double result=AFunction(x1)+AFunction(x2);     
 return (result);   
}

int main()  {
  x1=1.0;
  x2=2.0;
  r=AFunction(x1,x2,&res);

}
```

What I am interested in is to loop over the parameter(s) of the defined function, considering the fact that I would like to have the AFunction depending only on x.
That is, consider the function defined below:

```
// Simple Function
double AFunction(double x) {
  return ((x)+a);
}
```

I want to repeatedly call AFunction for different values of a which can be stored in a vector.

Comment: `double result, AA, BB, CC, DD, EE, FA, FB, FC, Tol1, PP, QQ, RR, SS, xm;` I hate all of those variable names. Try to change the include to `#include "brent_function.h"` or similar.

Comment: Can you maybe trim this to a minimal example of what your problem is?

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking... what do you mean by "loop over a function" ?

Comment: Its hard to decode what you are asking for, but I think you want to change the parameter to vector<double>

Comment: It's time to make up your mind as to whether this is C or C++?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean looping over parameters and calling a function, then you have to pass a parameters in come container, or use a variable length list.

```
double AddF( std::list<double> const& params) const
{
   double result = 0;
   for( auto& d : params) result += AFunction( d);     
   return result;   
}
```

Comment: This is not was I looking for. A much simpler answer was to pass an array to the function while going through the whole array in the main part of the C program.

Comment: well this exactly it, wrapped nicely in the function